# converting m/d/yy to mm/dd/yyyy in php

Tags: php

Im pulling column from excel with dates, and with the code i have to verify if row has date in it works fine for when dates in mm/dd/yyyy (07/05/2015) format. it passes date verify function and I'm able to grab that date and store it in mysql date formate column.  but problem comes in when I'm reading excel file that has date format m/d/yy (7/5/15) I'm not sure at what point its failing but when i look at it database the dates are converted to weird dates and its skipping most of the dates from failing at date verify function. what i would like to do is convert the string I'm fetching from excel from m/d/yy to mm/dd/yyyy before it gets to date verify function. can anyone tell me how can i achieve that?

this is my function to verify if its date.

```
public function is_date( $str ) /// function to check if its date
    { 
    $stamp = strtotime( $str ); 
    if (!is_numeric($stamp)) 
        return FALSE; 
    $month = date( 'm', $stamp ); 
    $day   = date( 'd', $stamp ); 
    $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp ); 
    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) 
        return TRUE; 
    return FALSE; 
    }
```

this is the part where it gets the date and sends to database

```
 foreach(array_slice($sheetData, $dateRow-1) as $item) 
            { 
                $value = trim($item["{$revCol}"], "$");
                $value = str_replace(",", "", $value);
                $value = str_replace("?", "", $value);
                //check if its date or garbage data
                if ($this->is_date( $item["{$dateCol}"]) /* && $this->isCurrency($temp) */)
                {   
                    $key = $item["{$dateCol}"];
                    $key = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($key));
                    $sold = $item["{$soldCol}"];
                    $params = array('key' => $key);
                    $oldVal->execute($params);
                    $results = $oldVal->fetch(); // fetch old value before replacing with new   
                    $old_rev = $results['rev'];
                    $old_sold = $results['sold'];
                    $diff_rev = $value - $old_rev;
                    $diff_rev = number_format($diff_rev, 2, '.', '');
                    $diff_sold = $sold - $old_sold;
                    //$insertDiff->execute(array($key, $diff_rev, $diff_sold));     
                    $newVal->execute(array($key, $value, $diff_rev, $sold, $diff_sold));
                }       
            }
```

Comment: Well, is that date July 5th, or May 7th? Don't expect miracles from strtotime() if the input is ambiguous. It doesn't know what you're thinking...

Comment: july  (m/d/yy) format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to convert it ...

```
$date = "7/5/15";
$your_date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));
echo $your_date;
```

It will echo 07/05/2015

[Here you have the example online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fcba2c2a21e6a852aeaeaca4ed95dea337bf7250)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? strtotime undestands such format

```
$str = '7/5/15';
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($str)); // 07/05/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the column in Excel as a date with leading zeroes.  That seems the quickest solution.

Comment: lol yeah but i have no control over that. i have to use what I'm supplied with.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime should do the work.

Try replacing '/' by '-'

```
$stamp = strtotime( str_replace('/', '-' ,$str ) );
```

If not, the problem happen all time with the format m/d/yy or just in some cases (for example for days greater than 12 or something like that ?

Comment: by doing that its skipping all the days after 12th